# More questions about binary numbers in base $n$

Tags: combinatorics

A sequel to this question: [A question about "binary numbers in arbitrary bases"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334440/a-question-about-binary-numbers-in-arbitrary-bases)

Here's the converse of that statement:

> Let a "binary number in base n" refer to a natural number whose representation in base n consists of only 0's and 1's.
>
> Given some collection of numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n\ (a_k \ge 2)$ so that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k-1} < 1$, there exists a natural number that *cannot* be expressed as the sum of binary numbers $b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots, b_n$ so that for all $1 \le k \le n$, $b_k$ is in base $a_k$.

How would you go about proving *this*? Could the gaps end up filling each other up? Is there a counterexample? I think I have an example involving continued fraction approximations of 1 by multiples of an irrational number, but I have no idea how to formalize it, and it was also lost to a deleted archive, so it will take some time to reformulate.

Comment: For example, in bases $3$ and $4$, you can't get $61$, and $\frac12 + \frac13 < 1$.

Comment: What does it mean for a binary number to be in, say, base $3$? Do you mean that the base $a_k$ expression for $b_k$ has only zeros and ones? (and, if so, could you edit the question to reflect that?)

Comment: It's in the previous question, but you're right, I suppose I should include the definition here as well.